# Как организовать проверку вставляемых значений в триггере Instead of Insert в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите с таким вопросом: нужно организовать проверку вставляемых значений на совпадения в триггере для вьюшки по ключевом полю и если есть уже такое значение, то завершение работы триггера.
Есть таблица с уже имеющимися в ней значениями:

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
 IDBook INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Amount INT NOT NULL,
 Price INT NOT NULL,
);
```

Есть представление:

```
create view Vbook
as
    select IDBook, Name, Amount, Price from Book
go
```

Есть триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON Vbook
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Book(IDBook, Name, Amount, Price) 
    SELECT IDBook, Name, Amount, Price
    FROM inserted
END
go
```

Как организовать проверку вставляемых значений на совпадения в триггере для вьюшки по ключевом полю и если есть уже такое значение, то завершение работы триггера?
К примеру, если в ключевом поле есть значение 5 и в insert into Vbook опять добавляется значение 5, то добавление не происходит и триггер заканчивает работу

Comment: `left join book ... where ,,, is null` ?

Comment: К примеру, если в ключевом поле есть значение 5 и в insert into опять добавляется значение 5, то добавление не происходит и триггер заканчивает работу

Comment: ```IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table WHERE id = INSERTED.id) THEN ..```

Comment: @monah все поняли что происходит.

Comment: @Akina инсерт то массовый может быть. или у instead of по одной записи? Надо в коррелирующий подзапрос в условие пихнуть.

Comment: @teran А. да, SQL Server же, у него per-statement triggers. Для массового - `INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS`, без IF.

Comment: @teran не совсем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам уже написали в комментариях, чтобы исключить уже присутствующие записи из вставки можно пойти двумя путями:

a) Джойн к существующей таблице. у тех записей, которых нет, соответствия не будет, их и оставляем.

```
 INSERT ....
 SELECT ...
 FROM inserted
 LEFT JOIN book AS b ON (b.id = inserted.id) 
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

б) коррелирующий подзапрос для фильтрации вставляемых записей

```
INSERT ...
SELECT ....
FROM inserted
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM book AS b 
    WHERE b.id = inserted.id
)
```

можно еще написать `where inserted.id not in (select id from book)` но не стоит.

вариант "б", наверное, будет наиболее эффективен

Comment: Спасибо большое!